# Calling a Restful web service in C

Tags: c, perl, web-services

I have a C program that I have to convert SQL queries to instead call a web service. Is there anyway you can call web services in C on a Unix machine? Re-writing the code is not really an option for since it's a good 5000 line program. One theory I have is for the C program to call a PERL script that calls and returns the output to me back to C. What options do I have to tackle this issue?

Comment: Of course. All things are possible in C. You could even write an entire operating system in C if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there anyway you can call web services in C on a Unix machine?*
>
> Is there a way to make HTTP requests in C on a unix machine?

Well, yeah. You could use libcurl, among others.

---

> *One theory I have is for the C program to call a PERL script that calls and returns the output to me back to C.*
>
> Can a C program execute a Perl script and capture its output?

Yeah. Just replace the child's STDOUT with a pipe and read from the pipe.

Comment: The problem with using LIBCURL, and i apologize for not specifying it before that its not available on HP Unix machines. Also how efficient would reading the output of a STDOUT be? i know that it's a ghetto way of doing it but there should be another way to do it via C itself.

Comment: It won't compile on HP machines? I find that hard to believe "*libcurl is highly portable, it builds and works identically on numerous platforms, including Solaris, NetBSD, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, Darwin, **HPUX**, IRIX, AIX, Tru64, Linux, UnixWare, HURD, Windows, Amiga, OS/2, BeOs, Mac OS X, Ultrix, QNX, OpenVMS, RISC OS, Novell NetWare, DOS and more...*"

Comment: We do not have it available for our HPUX machines. only our Linux have it unfortunately.

Comment: I don't follow. You keep saying it's not *available* to you, but it's available to whole world. The question is whether it *compiles* or not.

Comment: It doesn't compile because it does not exist on our machines. And i don't have the admin rights to install it. For some reason they will not install it on our Unix Machines. If I did have it , I bet it would compile just fine.

Comment: You should be able to do a local install for your own use without admin rights.